Selenium c# FindElement cannot find the recaptcha element to click
No matter how hard I try
I can’t click on an element

using (var driver = UndetectedChromeDriver.Create(
    driverExecutablePath: @"chromedriver.exe"))
{
    driver.GoToUrl("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo");
 
    var field = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("g-recaptcha"));
    field.Click();
 
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
 
    var fields = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("button-holder audio-button-holder"));
    Console.WriteLine(fields.Count);
}


Can you [edit] your question to include the relevant HTML as plain text? Images are good at illustrating the UI you are working with, but please include all code as code.
